# Is setting cgroup_enable=cpuset necessary in this case?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, kubernetes

I am setting up a raspberry pi based cluster using kubeadm and containerd as the CRI. I have 8GB nodes and I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on them. I need to setup cgroups and the various instructions in various places is confusing me.
I have seen the following to be setup in `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt`.

`cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1 swapaccount=1`

Currently `cat /proc/cgroups` is giving me the following output

```
#subsys_name    hierarchy       num_cgroups     enabled
cpuset  8       1       1
cpu     4       43      1
cpuacct 4       43      1
blkio   7       43      1
memory  0       51      0
devices 10      43      1
freezer 3       2       1
net_cls 2       1       1
perf_event      5       1       1
net_prio        2       1       1
pids    6       48      1
rdma    9       1       1
```

From the above I have 2 questions:

I believe this indicates that cpuset is already enabled and I believe that doing `cgroup_enable=cpuset` is unnecessary. Also memory cgroup is disabled and not set so the 2 memory commands are needed. Am I correct?

Moreover, I am finding conflicting guidance on `swapaccount=1`. Since swap is turned off for me anyway, is there a need to enable swap accounting?

Comment: did you figure this out? I am having cgroup issues with my Kubernetes cluster running on pi and think it's related. My current settings: `cpuset enabled` `memory enabled`. `cgroup_memory=1 `